# for remembering passwords, sessions or cookies or both?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

If a user decides to remember their password based on a checkbox when logging in, is it good practice to set both session and cookies? or would it be better to just do cookies?

I think I understand to do sessions when user logs in and DOES NOT like to remember the password.

Which one is good practice for remembering logging in?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't know, I prefer SESSIONs for keeping SESSIONs alive (not for storing a password; *NEVER* store a password on a client in plaintext anywhere, including a database, and I strongly recommend not even storing a hash of a password on the client without caution). Remembering a username, though, this I'm ambivalent about; as long as it's only for filling a username field on login, and not on rebuilding a logged-in state.

Comment: You could use LocalStorage for remembering the username. Safe and (very) easy. Using it for remembering the password too may be risky, but doable (browsers should restrict LocalStorage access from other websites and scripts).

Comment: @Artefact2 - Are the restrictions for LocalStorage different from the restrictions across domains for COOKIEs? What makes LocalStorage (if available) safer than a COOKIE?

Comment: Well, cookies are sent for every request on the domain. LocalStorage is just what it says on the tin. You just fetch from it to pre-fill the login form.

Comment: I'm only doing sessions to if a user logs in, they can go through pages without constantly logging in. I'm not storing any password in the sessions or cookies. I'm only storing ids into the cookies

Comment: @Artefact2 - Hmm, good point; I hadn't thought of that (using `https` ubiquitously would obviate that of course, but few do). Now, all I would say is that saving a plaintext (or even hashed) password value for authentication is the actual flaw, not the method used to break it. Better not to do so, what do you think?

Comment: If you're only trying to `Remember Username` for longer than a SESSION would last, using a COOKIE is just about the only way to do so, and I don't see anything (inherently) wrong with this. As long as it only populated a `username` field when a potential user from a browser tried to login.

Comment: Just for the record: OP is talking about "remembering that a user has logged in", not about "autocomplete the login form", that's the browser's task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a session gets killed by default after 20 minutes, what do you think is the best solution for long-time storage?

I hope you're not thinking of actually storing the password in either a cookie or a session, but to store some random ID you also store in your database, which you check on every page view?

Comment: Yeah, I'm only storing id... I think thats all i'm storing. `setcookie('remember',$id,$time)` where $id is the only variable being stored right?

Comment: Correct. I also hope it indeed is a random ID and not the User ID since that can easily be changed? If I alter my cookie to ID 1, will I have admin rights? ;)